# Multiple form with TinyMCE on one page

Tags: javascript, cakephp, tinymce, cakephp-2.5

I have multiple form (loaded in a loop) in one page and each form have a TinyMCE input but actually only the first is formatted with TinyMCE, the others are ordinary input.

I use this helper (cakephp 2.5 project) : http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/galitul/2012/04/11/helper_tinymce_for_cakephp_2

I try with :

```
<?=
$this->Tinymce->input('description', array(
    'name' => 'description',
    'id' => $value[$class]['id'],
    'value' => $value[$class]['description'],
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'type' => 'textarea',
    'label' => false,
    'placeholder' => __('Description')
),
array(),
'exact'); ?>
```

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: What exactly do the `$this->Form->create()` calls look like? Are they all using the same model name?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a well-known "bug."  Try dynamically changing the `id`s for each `textarea`.  Despite TinyMCE's claims that it'll render all textareas as TinyMCE widgets with the `textarea` selector, TinyMCE doesn't do so if all the `textarea`s have the same `id`.  It'll render the first one, encounter the second and think it has already render a widget for it since it has the same `id` as the last one.  That's why only the first `textarea` is rendering as a TinyMCE widget.

This is fair, I suppose, since `id`s are supposed to be unique identifiers in HTML: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/id-html-attribute/.